# How to give the permission to each user in winforms using c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, user-controls, user-permissions

How to give the User permission in winform?

**For Example**

My application is based on retail shops,so the every employee having username and password,the Super Admin(Manager) he needs to give the permission to each user

1. NOT all employees have the full rights to access all the forms.
2. In each forms they have to access only selected controls only
   for ex. User `x` have permission only for ADD and Edit only, but not To delete the record.
3. The User `x` not suppose enter discount more than 25%
4. The Super Admin Have the permission to allow access to every employee.

In this I need some logic references

may grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should develop a Role-Base windows application. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42750/A-Secure-Role-based-Windows-Form) tutorial describe what you need 
i hope it helps you

Comment: but now whats is the issues is,now the application is going to end,at end time my client asking to do this Role based.,whether its possible to change in every form...

Comment: The updated link is now a dead link. Please update or remove

Answer (score 1):

As Somewhere Mentioned above you need a role based architecture.
In your database Of users you should include role column.
At the time of user log in you have to get role of of the user having particular 
user name and password and store in some global static variable which can be used throughout 
application.
And according to role,set visibility true or false for each form on form load method.